# fetch data google analytics

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

libraries used for fetch google analytics data. When want to fetch data using libraries its redirecting gmail login after login its giving data, but it will set in cron jobs on server. not possible to manually login. so how to fetch google analytics data without gmail login or is there any way to automate login  with username and password and fetch data.. using libraries

```
define('CLIENT_ID', 'xxxxxxljg7pukglq.apps.googleusercontent.com');

/* Google App Client Secret */
define('CLIENT_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');

/* Google App Redirect Url */
define('CLIENT_REDIRECT_URL', 'http://localhost:8080/ga1/oauth2callback.php');
```

already have credentials and library which is working on manually login

Answer (score 0):

**Your Analytics account**

Assuming that you will be accessing your own data only.  Then you should consider using a service account.  A service account is a dummy user which you can then grant permissions to your google analytics account.  It will then be able to access your data without you having to preform a normal login

[Hello analytics php service account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php)

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$response = getReport($analytics);
printResults($response);


/**
 * Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 *
 * @return An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 */
function initializeAnalytics()
{

  // Use the developers console and download your service account
  // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
  // change the key file location if necessary.
  $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  return $analytics;
}


/**
 * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
 *
 * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}


/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
        print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
          print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Not Your Analytics account**

If you are not accessing your own data then you will have to stick with Oauth2 and authenticate the user once and request offline access save the refresh token and use that later to request a new access token.  There is no way around requesting the users permission the first time.

Comment: @dalmTO,  already using this code but still have to login for firstime manually when intting this index,php page.. and this folder will be in cron so it cant possible to login maually on server side.

Comment: No you are not.  This code is for Service account authentication and is not the same as Oauth2 authentication.  you are not seeing a login screen using this code and following this tutorial.  I suggest you look closer at the code.  You are probably confusing it with [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; PHP quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php) which will popup an oauth window when hosted on the web.  The code i have posted does **NOT** have an index.php page.

Comment: @dalmTO, i downloaded libraries.. put credentials accordingly and have service-account-credentials.json file which have credential so above code is in index.php. and there is condtion to check sesstion of 'accces_token' if noe found its caalling to "oauth2callback.php" page.